# MinHeap implementation in Java

Tags: java, heap

I have made my own MinHeap in Java. I would like to get review comments on the same.

```
package heap.minheap;

public class MinHeap {

private int[] heap;
private int size;
private int maxSize;
private static final int FRONT = 1;

public MinHeap(int maxSize){
    this.heap = new int[maxSize+1];
    heap[0] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    this.size = 0;
}

private int getParent(int position){
    return position/2;
}

private int getLeftChild(int position){
    return 2*position;
}

private int getRightChild(int position){
    return 2*position+1;
}

private void swap(int position1, int position2){
    int temp = heap[position1];
    heap[position1] = heap[position2];
    heap[position2] = temp;
}

private boolean isLeaf(int position){

    if(position > size/2){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void insert(int data){
    heap[++size] = data;
    int currentItem = size;
    while( heap[getParent(currentItem)] > heap[currentItem] ){
        swap(getParent(currentItem),currentItem);
        currentItem = getParent(currentItem);
    }
}

public int delete(){
    int itemPopped = heap[FRONT];
    heap[FRONT] = heap[size--];
    heapify(FRONT);
    return itemPopped;
}

private void heapify(int position){
    if(isLeaf(position)){
        return;
    }

    if ( heap[position] > heap[getLeftChild(position)] || heap[position] > heap[getRightChild(position)]){

        if(heap[getLeftChild(position)] < heap[getRightChild(position)]){
            swap(position , getLeftChild(position));
            heapify(getLeftChild(position));
        }
        else{
            swap(position , getRightChild(position));
            heapify(getRightChild(position));
        }
    }
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=1; i<= size/2; i++){
        output.append("Parent :"+ heap[i]);
        output.append("LeftChild : "+heap[getLeftChild(i)] +" RightChild :"+ heap[getRightChild(i)]).append("\n");
    }
    return output.toString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a package just for one class seems like overkill.  `package heap;` would have been enough, I think.

---

You should offer a `.getSize()` method, especially since this implementation has fixed capacity, which places the responsibility of avoiding overflow on the user.

---

Index 0 of the array is wasted.  I'm not worried so much about the 4 wasted bytes, but that it's an unnatural thing to do in a language with zero-based arrays.  This feels more natural:

```
public MinHeap(int capacity) {
    this.heap = new int[capacity];
    this.size = 0;
}
```

To make that work…

```
// Note use of static keyword
private static int getLeftChild(int position) {
    return 2 * position + 1;
}

private static int getRightChild(int position) {
    return 2 * position + 2;
}

private static int getParent(int position) {
    return (position - 1) / 2;
}

private boolean isLeaf(int position) {
    // Reuse getLeftChild() for consistency and ease of understanding
    return getLeftChild(position) >= this.size;
}

public String toString() {
    …
    // Reuse isLeaf() for consistency and ease of understanding
    for (int i = 0; !isLeaf(i); i++) {
        …
    }
    …
}
```

---

The output from `.toString()` is awkward, as many nodes can get printed more than once.  (Consider building a [tree-like representation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/43285/9357).)  For a tree like

```
     1
   /   \
  2     3
 / \   /
4   5 6
```

The output would be

```
Parent :1LeftChild : 2 RightChild :3
Parent :2LeftChild : 4 RightChild :5
Parent :3LeftChild : 6 RightChild :ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException!!!
```

To avoid ambiguity, it would be better to say "*Node:* … LeftChild: … RightChild: …".

Answer (score 7):

**Style**

- Dead code should be removed. `maxSize` is never used.
- Be consistent in your style. You should decide wether you use `this`. If a decision is made you should stick to it.

  Here i would suggest refactor the constructor to

  ```
  public MinHeap(int maxSize){
      heap = new int[maxSize+1];
      heap[0] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
      size = 0;
  }
  ```

**Simplification**

In the `isLeaf()` method you basically say if the condition is `true`, return `true` otherwise return `false`

> ```
> private boolean isLeaf(int position){
>
>     if(position > size/2){
>         return true;
>     }
>     return false;
> }
> ```

This can be simplified to return if the condition is `true`.

```
private boolean isLeaf(int position){
    return (position > size/2);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A few thoughts:

1. Heapify ensures only a section of the array follows the heap property.

   Consider array {9,8,7,6,5,4,3}. On calling `heapify(1)`, it will result in {8,6,7,9,5,4,3}.

   Heapify API name has the assurance that the whole array is converted to a heap by one call.
2. Some optimisation can be done by storing `getRightChild`/`getLeftChild` in temp variables to avoid multiple processing for same data.
3. `getLeftChild`/`getRightChild` may return index > `maxSize` i.e it does not check for array bounds (`toString` API), say, for array {1,2,3,4}.
4. Since the implementation forces the usage of array to start from 1 unlike the usual convention, do add a comment or avoid that.

Comment: This heap implementation starts at position 1. Does calling `heapify(0)` make sense?

Comment: Corrected it to 1.

Answer (score 5):

My thought is that `heapify` would be better off as a nonrecursive function, since you could easily just change it to a simple while loop:

```
private void heapify(int position){
    while (!isLeaf(position)){
        int left  = getLeftChild(position);
        int right = getRightChild(position);
        if (heap[position] > heap[left] || heap[position] > heap[right]){
            if (heap[left] < heap[right]){
                swap(position, left);
                position = left;
            } else {
                swap(position, right);
                position = right;
            }
        } else
            break;
    }
}
```

Minor things I noticed that no one has mentioned yet:

1. `toString` doesn't output anything for a size 1 heap.
2. Your spacing is at times inconsistent.  For example, here around the comma:

   `swap(getParent(currentItem),currentItem);`      `swap(position , getLeftChild(position));`

   There were also a few `if`s and `while`s with different spacing.  It's easier to read your code if your spacing is more consistent.

All in all it was fairly clean and easy to read and understand.